# JSF Ajax refresh issue

Tags: ajax, jsf

In my JSF page, I have a dropdown that needs to be populated onload of the page which is set in request scope, now I have a Ajax call that refreshes a part of the page.
           The Ajax piece works fine but the issue is on refresh it also calls the getter for the Dropdown and returns null ( because its in request scope). To me it makes no sense to call the getter for a component that's not part of the Ajax refresh. Am I doing it correct , please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to specify which component you'd like to refresh. Depending on whether you are using jsf2 or richfaces (or any other technology), it is different, but it is often said in an attribute of the action component called `render` / `reRender`

Comment: I am using IBM Ajax support, I have h:selectOneMenu loaded during preRender(init()), its in request scope, I am updating a panelGroup through an Ajax get Request hx:ajaxRefreshRequest, As I said before the panelGroup is updated, but the getter for SelectMenu is called and null pointer exception is being thrown,.. I would still want to show the drop-down after Ajax refresh, can you please elaborate your answer in this scenario

Comment: sorry, I have never seen ibm's jsf stuff. (And I wouldn't like to given my 'love' for IBM products)

Answer (score 0):

Change the scope of managed bean to Session...